# JMeter 5.2.1 - num threads and loop count

Tags: multithreading, performance, jmeter

Folks how exactly are requests being sent from JMeter. Given this configuration does it mean that JMeter will create 200 threads, and send concurrent requests in a loop 20 times. I would assume that this means that each thread blocks until the previous request finishes, and sends the next request, and that this process is done 20 times for each thread.

Let's say I have a sample request A, num threads = 2, and loop count= 5 I imagine the workflow to be as follows

- At time t0 Thread 1 -> send A to the target server
- At time t0 Thread 2 -> send A to the taget server
- At time t1 Thread 1 receives response, and sends A again to target server
- At time t2 Thread 2 receives response and sends A again to target server

Is this the correct workflow that JMeter will follow. Please note I am using version 5.2.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter starts all the Threads defined in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) within the bounds of the Ramp-Up period
2. Each JMeter thread does not depend on the other threads
3. Once started each Thread starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
4. When there are no more samplers to execute the thread starts the next iteration
5. When there are no more loops to iterate - the thread is being shut down

The actual concurrency depends on test duration and application response time, it can be checked using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) and [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listeners

You can easily track each virtual user/iteration using [__threadNum() function](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II) and special `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image]